# Mapping of (key) overrides mapping of `<C-(key)>`

Tags: key-bindings

I am wondering why I can't use a mapping for `<C-)>` when a mapping for `)` already exists.

`:imap` shows:

```
i  )           *@<C-R>=AutoPairsInsert(')')<CR>
i  <C-)>       * )
```

I expect to be able to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>)</kbd> and have `)` inserted. Instead, my cursor jumps as if I just pressed a an unmodified <kbd>)</kbd> key.

How can I keep my `)` mapping and have `<C-)>` work also?

Comment: Can you include the mapping lines from your vimrc? If you have written `iremap` instead of `inoremap` you'll have recursively declared the mapping (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776117/what-is-the-difference-between-the-remap-noremap-nnoremap-and-vnoremap-mapping) for more) and so `)` will expand to the previous `)` mapping. If this is the case it may be as simple as making the second mapping declaration `inoremap`

Comment: @ljden The `*` in the pasted output indicates that the `nore` form was used. See `:h map-listing`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from my terminal: If I run `cat`, pressing <kbd>Ctrl-)</kbd> and <kbd>)</kbd> give the same output.